# How can i implement CORS in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

How can I implement CORS in JQuery. I have been trying to implement a simple page **scraper** but it has Access-Control-Allow-Origin error.

**Here's my code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#start').click(function(){
var url=$('#url').val();
$.ajax({

url: url,
type: 'GET',
dataType: '',
success: function() { alert("Success"); },
error: function() { alert('Failed!'); },

});
```

Comment: show the complete error code.

Comment: if its a personal web you can use an extension that Allows to request any site with ajax from any source.  in chrome -- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Comment: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

Comment: Thanks for replying but  i am still getting this error-No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. @Tasos

Answer (score 0):

CORS is need server configurations too, so if you can't access your url destination using jquery it's probably because server configuration that not allowed

here an article about cors
http://enable-cors.org/server.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use **JSONP** and **callback** for this.

Ex:-

```
$.ajax({
    url : "http://your_url.com/test.php",
    dataType:"jsonp",
    jsonp:"callback",
    success:function(data)
    {
           alert("success");
    }
});
```

And define your **callback** function.

Further reading :[API Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: thanks for replying @RE350 but still getting error-Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <